# Processing mod_wsgi.input

Tags: python, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

I am newbie in python and mod_wsgi development. When I want to get data from POST i read `envron['wsgi.input']` and as a result I get `name=username&fullname=name&pass=password`. Now my question is how to split it to get that input as array. For example to read like `name = arraypost[0]`?

Comment: You should use a micro framework or WSGI component library that does all this for you as it will save you a lot of time and ensure it is done correctly. See Flask and Werkzeug for good examples.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the data and pass it into dict() to create a dictionary of key, value pairs:

```
post_dict = dict([item.split('=') for item in envron['wsgi.input'].split('&')])
print post_dict['name']
print post_dict['fullname']
print post_dict['pass']
```

Comment: Your dic is wrong, here is an example:post_dict=dict([('s', 4139), ('guido', 4127)]). You do not use round brackets

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The dict constructor doesn't require a list of tuples. It can take any iterable including a nested list of key-value pairs. Have you tried my code? It works.

Answer (score 1):

Here I'm demonstrating how to do it in Python 3. Using `urllib.parse.parse_qs` converts it to a dictionary of lists.

```
import urllib.parse

post = urllib.parse.parse_qs(environ['QUERY_STRING'])

# get value of first instance of POST var 'foo'
print(post.get(b'foo',[''])[0])
```

Note the use of `get()` above. The first argument is a byte string, the second argument is a default value. As I said, it's a dictionary of lists, and since we're immediately fetching from index 0, we want at least a zero-length string there so we don't go out-of-bounds.